# d3.js line function not iterating over entire array

Tags: d3.js, iteration, linechart

Folks-

I've been trying to add a line chart on top of a stacked bar chart, using the same data set. The stacked bar chart works fine, but I'm only getting one pair of points plotted by the line chart part of the function.

As the line chart will be using the same x axis, I reused that part of the function. The "y" part of the function is returning the correct values for the first two children of the "data" object, but then it's not going any further.

```
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { console.log(x(x.domain()[i])); return x(x.domain()[i])}); //34 and 92
    .y(function(d,i) { console.log(d[i].total); return d[i].total}); //124 and -70
```

then I call it:

```
svg.append("svg:path").attr("d", line1(data)).attr("class", "data1");
```

I've posted it in github:

https://gist.github.com/RCL1/6906892

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` is a nested structure of two arrays. What happens is that it takes the first element of the first array and the second of the second and draws that. As there are only two elements at the top level, only two points are drawn.

To draw the full line, pass in only a single element of `data` and adjust the line accessor accordingly -- in particular, there's no need to index into `d`. You probably also want to pass these values to your `y` scale before drawing them.

The full code would look something like this. Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pabQN/).

```
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d,i) { return x(x.domain()[i])})
      .y(function(d,i) { return y(d.total); });

svg.append("path").attr("d", line1(data[0])).attr("class", "data1");
```

As a general comment, please please please make numbers numbers and not strings. This will save you from all kinds of weird behaviour later on.

Comment: Thank you Lars- I'll take the comment about numbers under advisement! -RL